# Use reg in module A as the parameter of A's inner module B

Tags: verilog, iverilog

Sorry but I had to change the question because I found the example I gave before is very vague. So I wrote this code below in purpose of getting the last 7 digits of a binary number "a". Then display them as binary to the console. But I failed and got output of x instead. What should I do to fix this?

```
module mainBtF;             //first module
reg [31:0]a;
opcodeF opF(opcode, a);
initial
begin
   a = 32'b00110011;
   $display("opcode=%b", opcode);
   $finish;
end
endmodule

module opcodeF(opcode, in);     //second module
reg [6:0]op;
reg [31:0]temp;
integer i;
input [31:0]in;
output opcode;
assign opcode = op;
initial
begin
   temp = in;
   for(i = 0; i < 6; i = i + 1)
   begin
      op[i] = temp[i];
   end
end
endmodule
```

Comment: Your "call B" should be outside `initial` block.

Comment: oh yeah you're right. didn't even check it lol(plus I'm a total noob)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Verilog is a hardware description language (HDL) that tries to model hardware concurrency. The procedural `initial` blocks in each module execute at time 0, and you have a race condition. You need to set this up the that inner module responds to changes in the inputs, and you need to wait the output to change before you can display it.

```
module mainBtF;             //first module
reg [31:0]a;
wire [6:0] opcode; // you forgot this - Verilog assumes undeclared signals are 1-bit
opcodeF opF(opcode, a);
initial
begin
   a = 32'b00110011;
   #1 // wait for some time
   $display("opcode=%b", opcode);
   $finish;
end
endmodule

module opcodeF(
        output reg [6:0]  op, 
        input wire [31:0] in
);     //second module

integer i;
reg [31:0]temp;

always @(in)
begin
   temp = in;
   for(i = 0; i < 6; i = i + 1)
   begin
      op[i] = temp[i];
   end
end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I works now. I really appreciate it. Sorry but I still want to ask a question as I am a noob lol. Does this mean that whenever I call another module, the parameter input has to be a wire and the wire's value is passed by a reg in the "mother-moduel"?(i don't know what else to call this). So in this case mainBtF passes reg a to opcodeF as input but opcodeF actually takes the the value as a wire. Am I right about this?